# Как подключить библиотеки .net framework в .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

Мне нужно в свое проекте System.AppDomain. Проект на Core 2.0. Могу ли я подключить библиотеки из .net framework в своем проекте. Если да, то как мне это сделать?

Comment: например поставить из NuGet пакет [System.AppDomain](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.AppDomain/)

Comment: @Grundy у меня тогда ошибка что AppDomein, есть в Susyem.AppDomain и в System.RunTime.....как пофиксить не знаю

Comment: А зачем он вам? AppDomain'ы не поддерживаются в .NET Core. Есть хорошие шансы, что функциональность, которую вы от них хотите, можно получить и по-другому.

Comment: Возможно стоит описать задачу, которую ты хочешь решить с помощью AppDomain

Comment: @VladD, Grundy мне нужный AppDomain, чтобы подгрузить в новом AppDomain через Assembly.Load() мою dll, выполнить код из сборки загруженной при помощи dll и вернуть результат в нужный мне AppDomain.Так что я сомневаюсь что можно это задачу реализовать не используя AppDomain

Comment: @Влад: А зачем вам новый AppDomain? Почему вам не подходит выполнить код в текущем AppDomain'е?

Comment: @vladd потому что я не хочу в appdomain сервера загружать сборки, их потом нельзя будет выгрузить до тех пор пока сервер не отключить. У меня программа, сервис для игры а текстовые квесты. В базе храниться длл с конфигурацией этого квеста. Когда пользователь хочет поиграть в квест. Длл с конфигурацией загружается из базы. И если грузить все один домен, т.е. сервера будет не хорошо

Comment: @Влад: DLL загружается из базы? o_O Хм. Не, это не решается, AppDomain'ов вовсе нету в .NET Core (и не будет). Используйте отдельный процесс вместо этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак.

В .NET Core нету функциональности `AppDomain`'ов, и они не будут добавлены. Если вам нужна изоляция, запускайте ваши плагины в новом *процессе*, а для общения используйте WCF.

---

На текущий момент (2020 год) сборки можно [выгружать](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/unloadability) (начиная с .NET Core 3). Поэтому, возможно, имеет смысл грузить всё в единственный AppDomain, а потом выгружать. О загрузке плагинов можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support#load-plugins).