# Как сформировать из DataTable JSON для передачи его в js скрипт?

Tags: javascript, c#, json

**Первая часть вопроса:**

1) Как таблицу DataTable передать в скрипт на js?
Я использую такой контроллер:

```
public IActionResult SearchByName()
{
    string nameString = Request.Query.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "term").Value;
    string result = db.GetTable(nameString);

    return Json(result);
}
```

Это верный код контроллера?

**Вторая часть вопроса:**

2) Как потом по правильному распарсить полученный json в скрипте на js?

Answer (score 1):

Вроде нашел ответ, можно использовать System.Web.Script.Serialization;

```
public string DataTableToJSONWithJavaScriptSerializer(DataTable table) 
{  
    JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();  
    List < Dictionary < string, object >> parentRow = new List < Dictionary < string, object >> ();  
    Dictionary < string, object > childRow;  
    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows) 
    {  
        childRow = new Dictionary < string, object > ();  
        foreach(DataColumn col in table.Columns) 
        {  
            childRow.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col]);  
        }  
        parentRow.Add(childRow);  
    }  
    return jsSerializer.Serialize(parentRow);  
}
```

**Дополнение**: 
Если Вы используете .Net Core, то насколько я понял вы не сумеете воспользоваться всеми прелестями System.Web.Script.Serialization; так как у вас не получится подключить библиотеку System.Web.Extensions.dll. Насколько я понял из [этого обсуждения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/727169/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-net-framework-%D0%B2-net-core) в проект на Core 2.0. мы не можем подключить библиотеки из .net framework.

**Решение:** смиренно использовать магию из пакета Newtonsoft.Json;

```
private string DataTableToJSONWithJavaScriptSerializer(DataTable table)
{
    try
    {
        string JSONString = string.Empty;
        JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);
        return JSONString;

    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"\n\nОшибка:\n {ex}\n\n");
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Буду рад вашим коментариям